# Add content-encoding header on axios

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, axios, aws-api-gateway

I use API Gateway on AWS.

First, I activated CORS option and send a request on axios, then it worked.

And I activated content-encoding and I added axios option

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
```

Then CORS error occured.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Should be

```
     headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      },
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you add correct headers directly to your axios POST ?

Maybe you could try

```
axios.post(your-url, {
    headers: {
       'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
})
```